# How can I get two at least two results from a MySQL query with two different where clauses?

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a Query constructor and thus am somewhat constrained in that I can merely alter the construction of the query, not pull the results together from multiple queries.

Thus, I am looking for a way to return two results from a single table, with a column of group_name

- where group_name = ''
- where group_name != ''

I'd like to return exactly two results, one which meets each criteria. Is there some way to do this via WHERE clauses, subqueries, CASE, or control flow statements?

Note, cannot use UNIONs, due to this old, constrained, query builder, I can however do Group By, Where, and a few other things.

Ultimately, I believe it should be the same result set as if you combined these two queries:
SELECT * from business where group_name = '' LIMIT 1;
SELECT * from business where group_name != '' LIMIT 1;

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be a result for each "where"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM BUSINESS
GROUP BY (group_name='');
```

This returns the first record in the table for which `group_name` is '', and the first for which it `!=''`.

And if you wanted to select say one record each for `group_name` being '', 'asdf', or anything else, you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM BUSINESS
GROUP BY ( CASE group_name
           WHEN '' THEN 1
           WHEN 'asdf' THEN 2
           ELSE 3
           END );
```

This assigns a value of 1 to anything with `group_name` being `''`, a value of 2 to anything with `group_name` being `'asdf'`, and a value of 3 to everything else.

Since there is a `GROUP BY` it picks one record (the first occuring) for each.

(for your information: [`CASE` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-statement.html).)

Comment: Pretty sure "select * ... group by" never works. You need to specify aggregate functions: select count(x), sum(y), max(z)... group by

Comment: It does in MySQL. It's usually nonsensical to use it with non-aggregate columns, and if you do you get just one record from each group back. I only suggested it because OP seems to want just 1 record from each group.

Comment: Yes, I am using MySQL and can guarantee only MySQL, so it is quite good enough for my needs, and as mathematical.coffee figured out, I only need 1 of each result.

Comment: heh, cool. Is the semantics the same as LIMIT 1? ie: one quasi-randomly chosen row is returned?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I wouldn't count on it!

Answer (score 2):

Can you do a UNION?

```
(SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE group_name = '' LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE group_name != '' LIMIT 1)
```

And if you need to identify which record came from which set you can just alias a static field in each set:

```
(SELECT 'empty' AS group_name_status, * FROM businesses WHERE group_name = '' LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT 'notempty' AS group_name_status, * FROM businesses WHERE group_name != '' LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: I cannot in fact do a UNION, though a UNION does exactly what I want, thanks for the answer, I should have clarified that as not being an option.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the union keyword? http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-union-sql-tutorial/